# Use for as while with counter

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

Most of the times, while loop is used when we are checking for an event to happen in the while loop body. And for is mostly used when a "determined" number of iterations is given. Let us assume we need to know the number of iteration we are in, generally speaking:

General While loop:

```
bool flag = false;
int it = 0;
while (!flag)
{ 
    //... do something using it
    ++it;
    flag = getFlag();
}
```

General For loop, the iteration number is intrinsic to the loop:

```
for(int it = 0; it < N; ++it)
{
    //... do something using it
    if (getFlag())
        break;
}
```

However, for the case where the number of iterations is not set (that is, we are looping until the even occurs) I have never seen something like:

```
for(int it = 0; !getFlag(); ++it)
{
    //...do something using it
}
```

But I always see something like the first while loop I have written. Is there any real difference? Is it considered a better style the while loop? Because for me, the for loop is more compact and easy to read and follow.

Comment: It's correct, but it may look surprising to someone who's only used to seeing `for` used in the standard "increment up to some limit" way.

Comment: @dlf *"It's correct, but limited to the specific case where the check for the termination condition is the last step performed before beginning the next iteration"* -- Both the while and the for loop are identical in this behavior, so I'm not sure what your point here is.

Comment: `for` is nearly defined to be transformed to a  `while` loop at compilation time.

Comment: @dlf I do not get the point neither (as previous comment mentions). And I have fixed the code adding `!`

Answer (score 6):

Generally you should use whichever you find the most readable, but beware that **there is a difference between these two constructs** that may catch you off guard: the behavior of `continue`.

`continue` would not increment `it` using the `while` construct, but it would increment it using the `for` construct.

```
while (!getFlag()) {
    // ...

    if (something) {
        // "it" won't be incremented!
        continue;
    }

    // ...

    ++it;
}

for(int it = 0; !getFlag(); ++it) {
    // ...

    if (something) {
        // "it" will be incremented!
        continue;
    }

    // ...
}
```

If you are not using `continue` then the behavior will be identical, but you can't make the general statement that `for (a; b; c) { d; }` is exactly equivalent to `{ a; while (b) { d; c; } }` unless you add the restriction that `d` cannot contain a `continue` statement.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in execution between the while() and for() loops you describe. There is no standard or common convention on which one is better or more elegant. Stick to the one you find more comfortable to work with.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any real difference?

No. Apart from variable scoping and the meaning of `continue`, these are exactly equivalent:

```
initialize;
while (condition) {
  body;
  increment;
}

for (initialize; condition; increment) {
  body;
}
```

> Is it considered a better style the while loop?

There are, as you mention, typical use cases for each type of loop:

- If you have some initialization, test and increment, use a `for` loop. Not necessarily for a known number of iterations, either; a typical C++ pattern is to iterate while `i != some_container.end()`. I think your last example works fine as a `for` loop.
- If you don't need the initialization and increment, use a `while` loop. Writing `for (; condition;)` is just silly.

However, there are grey areas, where either type of loop makes sense. It is mostly a matter of personal preference.

Comment: No, they are not equivalent. If `body` contains `continue` then `increment` would be skipped in the `while` case but not in the `for` case.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above cases are valid, and perfectly OK in my book (assuming that you meant to set `flag = true;` in the first case, or at least not constant `false`, since that will never enter the loop).

I sometimes use:

```
 for(int i = 0; ; i++)
 {
    ...
    if (getFlag()) break;
    ... 
 }
```

Another favourite is the typical "linked list loop":

```
for(Node* p = head; p; p = p->next)
{
    ... Do stuff with p ... 
}
```

To a large degree, it depends on what you are actually trying to express...

The compiler will most likely generate the same, or at least very similar, code for all three.

Comment: I had a bug in the example code about flag, which I corrected already.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was the case. And by the way, if the `getFlag()` function returns `false` on the first call in your last example, it would also not enter the loop (same as for an empty list in my second example).

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that

```
for (exp1; exp2; exp3) {
   statements;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{   // I put the brace, because exp1 may be a declaration of variable local to the loop
   exp1; 
   while (exp2) {
      statements;  // as long as there is no continue (or if you replace every continue; with { exp3; continue; } 
      exp3; 
   }
}
```

So it's a matter of taste,  of having a loop specific initialisation and an increment expression, and of the way of using `continue` statements .

However your analysis is exact:  `for` is frequently used for iteration, as the c++11 range-for shows :

```
for (x : container) {
   statements; 
}
```

The reason (at least according to B.Stroustrup) is that all control logic for the iteration can easily be regrouped in one visible place, at top of the loop.

Comment: No, they are not equivalent. If `statements` contains `continue` then `exp3` would be skipped in the `while` case but not in the `for` case.

Comment: @cdhowie you are of course perfectly right ! But does this change the general statement that it's basically the same construct and a matter of taste ?

Comment: Yes, somewhat -- there are cases when you would prefer one over the other not because of taste but because you need to use `continue` and need the behavior to be one way or the other.

Comment: But isn't `continue` itself a matter of taste and style ?  You can always rewrite a conditional continue construct into a conditional construct without continue.  But the fact that we continue to discuss about it shows that the question is primarily opinion based, and I'm pretty sure that we both would certainly choose while or for in a very similar manner ;-)

Comment: To a certain degree, sure... I mean, with any turing-complete subset of the language we can emulate any other turing-complete subset, right? Who needs classes? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'll agree with most people there is no major difference (and in fact in most situation they will actually compile down into the same code). I was always taught not to use for loops in situations where internal operations (other than the iterator) could change when the loop ends. This was for readability sake.